# angular CookieService instance initiation error

Tags: angular, cookies, http-headers

I have a class where I want to use the CookieService to get a value but I can't seem to be able to initial CookieService what am I missing here please? (I'm new to angular)

I'm getting "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" error

```
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ErrorObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

export abstract class ComponentService {

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) { }

  baseURL: String = 'http://localhost:8080';

  public getHttpOptions(){
    let auth:String = this.cookieService.get('Authorization');
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': String(auth)
    });
    return headers;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add @Injectable() decorator above your ComponentService. And also add both ComponentService and CookieService to the providers array.

Comment: I had ComponentService and CookieService in the providers array but @Injectable() fixed the issue thanks